# Error when uploading image php

Tags: php, json, image, upload

Hello I have a problem with croppic script when i choose photo to upload i see this error in firebug console

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

and this error in photo url :

```
{"status":"success","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/icareer\/temp\/10505530_522065094589095_8292243821778754473_n.jpg","width":960,"height":768}
```

any one can help me ?

Comment: "success" is an error? I think you've posted the wrong line, because it looks valid to me.

Comment: same problem here. 

my response - {"height":992,"status":"success","width":806,"url":"/web/profile/picture?c=ec9c8fc0421f42ad878c5a265b4f7f95"}

but getting error - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

i think i fixed this.

earlier when my response Content-Type was **application/json**, i was getting this error - 
***SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data***.

but changing  response Content-Type to **text/plain** solved the problem.

weird!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, my content-type was text/javascript. Changing this with "text/plan" like Krishnendu said, solve the problem for me or you can just delete the content-type.